# M-< and M-> doesn't work as it should in emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Using M-< gives me "Marker stack is empty"
and  M-> gives me "Find definitions of:" in the mini buffer,
instead of taking me to the beginning and end of a file.

How do I use them so that they work properly?

Answer (score 2):

The actual commands are `M-shift-<` and `M-shift->`. In other words, you actually need to type the characters '<' or '>'. Testing with my own version of emacs, it seems that you are currently entering the commands `M-.` and `M-,`.